# how to setup hmvc in codeigniter 3 dev?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc, codeigniter-3

I started a new project and I want to use the new version of codeigniter 3.0 dev, but after the download I install the hmvc extension and don't find the base controller. How can I fix this or maybe is another solution for making the codeigniter modular? And please don't come up with solutions of other frameworks or so.i love codeigniter and I stay with him and sorry for my Eng :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use CodeIgniter 3.0 for almost two years. So, I have "met the Spartans" yet, and I have published my work.

You may choose between two platforms:

https://github.com/ivantcholakov/starter-public-edition-3 - a traditional one, it uses HMVC by wiredesignz, adapted for CI3.0.

or

https://github.com/ivantcholakov/starter-public-edition-4 - an innovative (and therefore risky) platform, very similar to the previous one, in addition it is intended to support multiple (dependent on each other) applications within a single site.

On both of the platforms I upgrade CodeIgniter 3.0-dev constantly.

See the README files for these platforms. There are live demo's too. There are also programming examples for demonstration of some added features and for testing.

Good luck!

Comment: is good to use codeigniter or what do you think? what is your opinion?

Comment: @msa_dev Its development is conservative, this is important for me. CodeIgniter 3-dev is good, CodeIgniter 2.x is too old.

Comment: can you help me with more one issue please if you don't mind? i have a stack with update into database but not to update the fields theats is not set. i already see something here but is not for my setup.can you give me your contact or something. like this we can talk more about this.tnks

Comment: @msa_dev My email is visible from my github account ivantcholakov. But write me for a thing, that is to be solved quickly.

Or, if you use some of the platforms, you may open an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Pull request at CI github > https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/1818 ..
Its about HMVC..

But know that its not supported so you will have to "Meet the Spartans"

Comment: tnks man i apreciate ;)